# STS on Linux - Could Not Calculate Build Plan

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

After installing the Spring Tool Suite, I tried to create a maven project and this is what I get in an instant:

[image]

[image]
[image]

So waddap Maven/STS creators? How do I make your product work?

Comment: Based on the message I bet you have errors during the build of not downloadable artifacts or network issue...Best is to test on plain command line and see the log output...

Comment: thanks for the reply good sir. i havent any idea how to use the command line either. im trying to learn this Java Spring thingamajig but these errors are just hampering my curiousity haha. how do i delete maven repositories, if any (coz i've no idea where they're located)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any noobs like me who got overwhelmed by this error, here's what I did:

1. Go to your .m2/repository, where I think Maven stores its configurations files, then wipe it clean, delete all files, delete the 'repository' folder even.
2. I then closed the STS IDE and restarted it. You can see in 'Progress tab' that Maven is downloading new files.
3. Saw the same 5 errors, right clicked and clicked 'Quick Fix'. That's it.

[This post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/87300-could-not-calculate-build-plan) was helpful too.